# How do I get a field of a datatable when I know column name and a row ID, without looping?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, datatables

How do I get a field of a datatable when I know column name and a row ID, without looping?

For instance; I want the “Total Sold” value when Region = City and Product = Legos. This is something I have struggled with for a long time, probably because I think in SQL so looping through everything all the time doesn’t always seem like the correct way to go. BUT if I just need to learn to think like a VB developer and always loop to get something out of a list or table, please let me know.

I have a series of asserts comparing two datatables, one that has one row with a named column for each cell (from XML produced by SSRS), and another datatable that has one row for each unique value in a region (produced from a SQL query).

Table from SQL (mockup dataset):

```
Region  Prod  Total Sold
City    Legos   68
State   Legos   90
Nat.    Legos   200
City    ToyB    20
State   ToyB    30
Nat.    ToyB    40
City    ToyC    450
State   ToyC    600
Nat.    ToyC    900
```

Table from XML (dataset returned from SSRS):

```
City_Legos  State_Legos  Nat_Legos  City_ToyB  State_ToyB Nat_ToyB City_ToyC State_ToyC 
68          90           200          20           30     40       450        600
```

The part of the assert statement that gets data from the XML based datatable is easy, because there is only one row (index 0), and I can just name the column I want:

```
Dim xmlRow As DataRow = xmlDatatable.Rows(0)
Assert.AreEqual(“my SQL cell goes here”, xmlRow.Field(Of Integer)(“City_Legos”))
```

And I can do one assert for each of the specified columns.  Many of the columns won’t be tested, and they have specific names, so I can’t simply loop through the columns. So what do I put in “my SQL cell goes here” to return the Total Sold for City and Legos? Obviously in SQL it would be easy: SELECT TOP 1 Total_Sold WHERE Region = City and Prod = Legos.
I am currently looping through the SQL datatable and testing each cell for my criteria, but that logic gets huge because I have to wrap each like in If…Then, like this:

```
For Each m As DataRow In mySqlTable.Rows

If m.Field(Of String)("Prod") = "Legos" Then
    If m.Field(Of String)("Region") = "City" Then
        Assert.AreEqual(m.Field(Of Integer)("TotalSold"), xmlRow.Field(Of Integer)(“City_Legos”))
    End If
    If m.Field(Of String)("Region") = "State" Then
        Assert.AreEqual(m.Field(Of Integer)("TotalSold"), xmlRow.Field(Of Integer)(“State_Legos”))
    End If
    If m.Field(Of String)("Region") = "Nat" Then
        Assert.AreEqual(m.Field(Of Integer)("TotalSold"), xmlRow.Field(Of Integer)(“Nat_Legos”))
    End If
End If
Next
```

I’m hoping I can do something like a select or LINQ or Function?
Something like this would be nice:

```
Dim result as Integer =  mySqlTable.Select.First(“Region = City and Prod = Legos“)
```

Or:

```
Assert.AreEqual(mySqlTable.Select.First(“Region = City and Prod = Legos“), xmlRow.Field(Of Integer)(“City_Legos”))
```

This is a unit test, so I will always know the column and field names returned by SSRS.

Getting the cell by Column name and row identifier has always been something I’ve struggled with, so hopefully I can finally get this solved.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a list of elements and you want to select the ones fulfilling certain conditions, you would have to search through this list (= loop through it) until finding what you want. This is the only available option for both humans and computers :) VB.NET has quite a few "shortcuts" to write a loop in a quite summarised way (for example: LINQ queries), but these are loops anyway. Usually, when you say "no loops" you mean something like LINQ, but just want to make this point clear. Also that LINQ does not have to be more efficient than conventional loops (depends upon the situation).

Comment: @varocarbas - Thanks so much. I thought the answer might be "you should always loop". I normally do, because the SSRS data generally tabular, but in this case it's singleto.  Of course I can still loop, but still, I wanted to find the singleton value. Thanks, this helps my general understanding of processing data in VB.

Comment: Nothing to do with VB.NET; it has to do with programming (and well... common sense). If you have a list of elements and want to know in which position is the element you have; you have two options: lucky guess (computers don't do that) or looking all the elements until finding the one want. The fact that a programming language has lots of "fancy things" cannot hide the reality: at the end, everything are loops and conditions (loop through all the elements and check if...). Not knowing that implies a serious basic-understanding of programming which you should look at.

Comment: ... if you are programmer, you cannot expect things to just happen (this is a user of the programs you should build; a magic believer), you should understand why things happen. If you think twice about what you intend to do, you would understand that there is no sensible, no-magic based way to find where an element is inside a list without checking the elements in the list :) Anyway... you are welcome. Here to help.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate knowing when I need to pick up an important concept. I thought I could do something like SQL, where I have never had to use cursors (looping). Regardless of whether or not SQL loops in the background, I never had to write a loop in SQL. Anyway, accepted answer works great for my current project. Thanks again.

Comment: LINQ is the .NET equivalent to SQL. With LINQ you don't write any loop; I explained it in my answer. But loops are always present. The convention is associating loops with for, while, etc. but the reality is that any collection-analysis function includes loops. This is a basic idea (programming is formed basically by loops and conditions) that any programmer should have clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Datatable Compute method.  Replace (“my SQL cell goes here” with 
CInt(mySqlTable.Compute("SUM([Total Sold])", "[Region] = 'City' and [Prod] = 'Legos'"))
This is assuming that the rows are unique and no null values.

Comment: Well, that certainly does the trick, thanks! I'm trying to figure out a way not to use SUM, but rather something like First(), on the off chance there are duplicate rows.  However this works great for now, considering there should always only be unique rows.

Comment: So, what does Compute exactly? Is it magic-based or loops-based?

Comment: I used to have 13 lines of looping code for every 5 asserts, now I have five lines of code for five asserts, resulting in a reduction of 8 lines of code.  Multiply that by the 16 sets I need to test, I just saved 128 lines of code. However, it is great to know that in memory it is still looping.

Comment: @BClaydon and what you think that LINQ is for? to reduce size of code (for those who care, not myself). BUT, this cannot make you think that now things are quicker: the loops are done anyway and things might be even slower. If you prefer this option, excellent; but your question was clarifying-worhty: without looping, you cannot analyse any collection.